# Is there anyway to play MP4 file on my iMac from a iPad Pro wirelessly?

Tags: mac

I have an iMac and I have some mp4 videos in it. I'd like to play it from my iPad Pro remotely. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you want to put the mp4 videos from the iMac onto your iPad and view them on the iPad? (Use iTunes to move the videos to the iPad). Do you want to move the mp4 videos to the iPad but display them on the iMac? (Use iTunes to move the videos to the iPad and then AirPlay the playback to your iMac) Do you want to leave the videos on the iMac and display them on the iMac but control playback via the iPad? (Not sure how to do this, or if it's possible)

Comment: Thanks. I want to play the files remotely without copying them. Just like I were watching a YouTube video but the source of the vid is the iMac

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave the videos on the iMac but display it on the iPad, you could put them into iTunes on the iMac and then turn on Home Sharing on the iMac. This will allow iTunes to make your iTunes library available to any Apple device on your home network. (The videos will be in "Home Videos" in iTunes. In iOS 10.2, you use the TV app to play iTunes video content.)  You must also be signed into the same AppleID on both devices, and the iMac must be turned on.

If you don't want to (or can't) use iTunes, Plex can do something similar. Plex offers many additional features, but it is also more complicated to set up.